# Is the JEITA battery charging temperature standard accepted by EN62368-1?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, safety, temperature

EN62368-1 Annex M.4.2.1 mandates that the battery charging circuit shall 'stop charging' when the temperature of the battery exceeds the highest specified charging temperature (typically 45°C). However, most Li-ion chargers ICs follow the [JEITA Temperature standard](https://home.jeita.or.jp/upload_file/20210407112651_JbDgUSWGiB.pdf). JEITA seems to have done thorough research on the topic of battery charging at high temperatures and their guideline states:

> [ ... ] When charging in the upper temperature range (45-60°C), a higher quantity of lithium migrates from the active cathode material. Because this increase in migrating lithium lowers the stability of the cathode’s crystalline structure, it decreases the battery’s safety. At the same time, it decreases the relative temperature difference between the upper temperature range and the range in which thermal runaway occurs. This makes it easier for the battery to experience thermal runaway if something like an internal short circuit happens. Consequently, the maximum charge voltage and/or the upper temperature range must be modified when charging within the upper temperature range. [ ... ]

It only mentions charge voltage explicitly, why is that?

However, EN62368-1 does not accept this and mandates that charging is cut off completely above 45°C. It seems to me that EN62368-1 writers were just lazy and swept everything that is above 45°C under the rug. Does anybody have any idea as to why EN62368-1 does not accept the JEITA temperature standard, while a lot of Li-ion charger ICs follow this standard, and JEITA has clearly done their homework on the matter of battery safety?

Does anybody have any experience with passing EN62368-1 testing with a Li-ion battery charger that follows JEITA temperature standard?